# Guideline 3.2.2(viii) - Business - Other Business Model Issues - Unacceptable

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

We noticed that your app facilitates trading in contracts for difference ("CFDs") or other derivatives, which is not appropriate in all the locations where the app is currently available. Your app should only be available to users in regions where you have the necessary licensing and permissions.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, you must take the following steps:

- Provide documentary evidence that you have the necessary licensing and permissions for all the regions where you want to distribute your app. Please attach your documentation in the App Review Information section in App Store Connect.

In accordance with section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you acknowledge that submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account and the removal of your apps from the App Store.

** We have provided all the documents and licences into Information Section, still they have rejected app and given same reason, please help.

Comment: Have you set the available regions for your app in App Store connect to match the regions for which you have provided documentation?

Comment: @Paulw11 Document which we have attached is basically prove that we are the authorised person to use this name and have copyright for that, but I don't know how to get permission to use application into particular region.

Comment: Apple's objection doesn't seem to be anything to do with your app name or copyright.  They want you to prove that your company holds the required financial services licenses in the geographies where you want to make your app available.  This would typically be provided by a government department; e.g. APRA in Australia or the SEC in the US

Answer (score 0):

we are also having the same rejection from Apple. We operate as a technology provider - providing a white-label app for clients, we are not registered as a broker-dealer in any of the clients' jurisdictions. We tried explaining that to Apple by providing our business profile as a software company but they are still rejecting our app and want us to provide financial service licenses for regions where we want our App to be made available.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This answer doesn't really provide a solution to the problem, and would be better as a comment or another question.